# Creating a beginners app using Django/Python: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pages'

Tags: python, django, macos, python-3.7

I'm new to Django and am trying to create a very simple app off of a tutorial I found online.

Working on a mac

Django Version 2.0.7

Python 3.7.0

My file structure:

helloworld

......venv

..........(other files)

......helloworld_project

..........(other files)

......manage.py

......pages

.........._ pycache _

..............otherfiles

..........admin.py

..........apps.py

..........migrations

..............(other files)

..........models.py

..........tests.py

..........urls.py

..........views.py

The problem:
when I run my urls.py file, I get the following message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Bethany/Desktop/helloworld/pages/urls.py",         
line 3, in <module>
    from pages import views
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pages'
```

My urls.py file:

```
# pages/urls.py
from django.urls import path
from pages import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.homePageView, name='home')
]
```

I've tried replacing "from pages import views" with 
"from . import views" and get the same message.

I've looked through a few similar questions on stack overflow, but haven't had success with finding a solution to fix my issue. does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks!

If needed, this is the tutorial I'm following: https://djangoforbeginners.com/hello-world/

Comment: Did you add `pages` to your `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py` as described in that tutorial?

Comment: @selcuk yes I did and then rechecked and checked again because I thought that was the issue too! It's there. :/

Comment: Do you have a file named `__init__.py` in `pages` folder?

Comment: Have you tried importing with the config (and defining the config? ) ex 
`
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'pages.apps.PagesConfig'
    # ...
]
`

Comment: @selcuk I just checked and it's there inside the pages folder

Comment: Execute ```pwd``` command and post the output pls

Comment: You don't normally 'run' url.py. Are you starting your app with ./manage.py runserver? See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial01/

Comment: @Keith John Hutchinson that may be my issue! I was starting my app with manage.py runserver, but just assumed that I’d have to run the additional files in Python IDLE as I was adding code to them. Do any specific files need to be run in IDLE when building apps on Django?

Comment: None that I'm aware of.

Comment: @Keith John Hutchison thanks for the help. So the error coming up in Python IDLE makes no difference then?

Comment: To run a django server you don't need IDLE. If you want to poke around with the models I suggest installing django-extensions https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions and then use ./manage.py shell_plus which wi load all of the models your working with.

Comment: @Keith John Hutchison thank you for all your help and explanations!

Comment: Cheers. Have fun :-) Python is a great language to work with and Django is an awesome framework to work with!

Answer (score 2):

The exact same thing happened with me today, turns out i was missing the comma after 'pages.apps.PageConfig'.
Super silly mistake

Comment: Good spot, this was the issue I face, wish the error responses were better

Answer (score 0):

Since the urls file is already in the app pages you can't import it using the said name. I would suggest you change `from pages import views` to `from . import views`

Answer (score 0):

since the `urls.py` and and `views.py` in the same directory therefor you can simply do `from . import views` it will import all the views.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem minutes ago, but the only issue which caused this same problem for me was a typo in configuring my app in the settings.py
instead of 'pages.apps.PagesConfig' i wrote 'pages.apps.pagesconfig'
and then the problem was solved frequently quickly.